# Linq - Retrieve a single value in a String

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I use Asp.net 3.5 and EF 4.

I need find a specific row in my DataBase and display on a label a single value as string.

At the moment I use this code, it is working, so I find a single Object and read its properties.

```
 var myAuthor = (from at in context.CmsAuthors
             where at.AuthorId == myRow.AuthorId
             select at).Single();   
 myAuthorNameLabel.Text = myAuthor.LastName;
```

I would like to know:

- If there is another syntax in Linq to achieve the same result.
- How to do it using Lamba?
- Which approach would you suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
 var myAuthorName = 
(from at in context.CmsAuthors where at.AuthorId == myRow.AuthorId select at).Single().Select(a => a.LastName);
```

actually this would be even better:

```
var myAuthorName = 
(from at in context.CmsAuthors where at.AuthorId == myRow.AuthorId select at).Select(a => a.LastName).Single();
```

### Update

An example of how to use with Anonymous type:

```
var myAuthorNames = 
    (from at in context.CmsAuthors where at.AuthorId == myRow.AuthorId select at).Select( a => new {a.LastName, a.FirstName}).Single();
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me why your second option would be even better?

Comment: Sure, the usage of `Single` executes the actual database query, so in the first case the query retrieves the entire Author object and then selects the last name out of it. The second method performs a minimal db query to retrieve only the last name column.

Comment: Ok I understand, what about using Anonymous Type? Could make even minimal db query? thanks for your help on this

Comment: In this case I don't think it can get any minimal that that. If you needed to retrieve two values then selecting an anonymous type would get you the minimal query.

Comment: Thanks Variant, may I ask you if you can write down here an example with Anonymous Type? Unfortunately I'm trying but with no success. Thanks once again!

Comment: added an update to the original post with an example of Anonymous type

Answer (score 4):

Here's the method syntax (using lambdas)

```
myAuthorNameLabel.Text = context.CmsAuthors
                           .Where(at => at.AuthorId == myRow.AuthorId)
                           .Select(at => at.LastName) 
                           .SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```